# How long can I store mole?

Tags: food-preservation, mexican-cuisine

I'd like to have a go at making some kind of *mole*, but all the recipes I have seem to make big batches. How long can I keep *mole* for, either in the fridge or freezer?

Comment: Making mole is not a small endeavor, so I'm glad you're planning on storing a big batch rather than scaling down!

Comment: Go big or go home, I always say.

Comment: I'm sorry, every time I see this title, all I can think is that you've been hunting [moles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(animal))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the freezer, more-or-less indefinitely, depending on how good your freezer is.  Certainly months to years.

In the fridge, it depends on the kind of mole.  Quick moles (like various green moles) don't keep very long, maybe a week at most.  A long-cooked mole should keep a bit longer -- up to 2 weeks -- since all of the ingredients are completely cooked.

If you're not planning to use it within a week, though, why not freeze it?  The texture won't take any harm from freezing and thawing.